# interactive widget based dashboard in javascript

Tags: javascript, widget, dashboard, interactive

I have seven widgets (div/iframe). In first widget, I can select a date and other six widgets have date based data drawn on google map. I want to create a dashboard where if I change the date in first widget, other widgets reflect/redraw data accordingly on map rendered in them. i.e. Other six widgets should reflect/display same date based data on map as the date which is chosen in first widget. Is there any way I can accomplish it?

Comment: Can you share ehat code you have so far?

Comment: Depends on how it's all set up. It's more than possible -- it's doable. But we can't help without more information.

Comment: Date can be selected in date parent widget. Other six child widgets draw treatment routes on google map. Treatment routes are stored in Postgres table with columns (id, date, polyline, chemical). Six Child widgets will draw polylines/routes  treated by certain chemical on a certain date which will be the date chosen in parent date widget.